# 2 x-axis, 1 of index and 1 using timestamp points, same y

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I have a timeseries and I would like to have 2 x-axis, 1 displaying the data-index and one it's corresponding timestamp. One way to do this seems to use the `plt.plot_date` and then plot again against the index. However:

1. there must be a better way to do it
2. the plot against dates is not picking up all the data(you can see the "gaps" below).

[image: dataplot vs indexplot.]

Red is the dates plot, blue the index plot.

- Is there a way I can initially set the "dates" xaxis equal to the
  "index" xaxis, and then change the tick labels to the corresponding
  dates?
- Also do you know why I might be getting the gap behavior when using
  `plt.plot_date`?

Original format of timestamps is in `str`:
`array(['2017-02-14 05:48:00', '2017-02-14 05:49:00', '2017-02-14 05:50:00', '2017-02-14 05:51:00', '2017-02-14 05:52:00', '2017-02-14 05:53:00',...]`

```
x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for d in dates_test]
x = [mdates.date2num(i) for i in x]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, figsize=(8, 6), sharex = True)

ax[0].plot(xaxis, errors)
ax4 = ax[0].twiny()
ax4.plot_date(x, errors, fmt="r-")
ax4.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m \n%H:%M'))
```

Comment: You can try and [edit the ticks](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html) to your desired values, and [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_parasite_axes2.html) could be usefull

Comment: Also, the plot against dates seems to be picking up all the data, it just isn't spreading it around as smoothly as the plot against the indexes, but clumped around a few dates. Are you sure the time stamps are all equally spaced and correctly converted?

Comment: @berna1111 Thanks for your reply. i)  I don't think that the example mentioned helps in this case. ii) thats a good point. the timestamps are not equally spaced, but this just how they are. That is why I would like to use them as tick labels, than actual ticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After generating data similar to yours:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ioff()
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt
import time

# --- Build date blocks ---
now = time.time() # first time
delta_time = 60 # distance between points in seconds

n_jumps = 10 # number of pieces with no data
avg_jump_size = 60*60*24 # 86400 s = 1 day
jumps = abs(np.random.normal(avg_jump_size/2.,
                             avg_jump_size/2,
                             n_jumps+1)) + avg_jump_size/2.
# `abs` just to make sure the jump is positive, and ` + avg_jump_size/2.` to
# make sure it's larger than the time step.

avg_n_poins_per_block = 2*60*60/delta_time # 2 hours of acquisition per block
blocks_sizes = abs(np.random.normal(avg_n_poins_per_block/2.,
                                    avg_n_poins_per_block/2.,
                                    n_jumps+1)) + avg_n_poins_per_block/2.

times = np.array([]) # array to place all dates
for i in range(n_jumps):
    block = np.arange(now, now+delta_time*blocks_sizes[i], delta_time)
    times = np.concatenate((times, block))
    now += jumps[i]
# last block
block = np.arange(now, now+delta_time*blocks_sizes[-1], delta_time)
times = np.concatenate((times, block))

def time2mdate_str(number=None):
    """
    Convert a time given by `time.time()` to a `datetime` instance
    from `matplotlib.mdate`.
    """
    if number is None:
        number = time.time()
    # time.time() returns the number of seconds since the Epoch
    # (1970-01-01 00:00:00).
    # But mdate represents time in days since 0001-01-01 00:00:00, plus 1 day.
    # (http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html)
    # So we convert to days:
    number /= 60*60*24
    # and then we add the 1969 years:
    # http://www.rapidtables.com/calc/time/days-in-year.htm
    number += 1969*365.2425
    # and now it should be off by only (!) ~11h (close enough)
    a = mdates.num2date(number)
    return a

# list of time strings:
dates_test = [time2mdate_str(t).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for t in times]
# some random data:
errors = np.random.normal(0.025, 0.01, len(times))
xaxis = np.arange(len(errors)) # omiter

# Original code:
x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for d in dates_test]
x = [mdates.date2num(i) for i in x]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, figsize=(8, 6), sharex = True)

ax[0].plot(xaxis, errors)
ax4 = ax[0].twiny()
ax4.plot_date(x, errors, fmt="r-")
ax4.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m \n%H:%M'))

fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

[image]

My first thought was to separate each block of data (you can still subtract the initial hour, to have the first x value be 00:00):

```
# break into blocks:
x = np.array(x)
deltas = x[1:] - x[:-1]
# assume there's no break right after the first value and
# find where the difference between consecutive times is larger
# than 1.1*deltas[0] (margin of 1.1* for float comparison)
break_indexes = np.where(deltas > deltas[0]*1.1)[0]+1
# add borders (will be useful for iterating over the list):
break_indexes = np.concatenate(([0],break_indexes,[-1]))
n_jumps = len(break_indexes) - 1
# offset to make sure each line does not overlap with another:
offset = 1.5*np.max(errors)

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
for i in range(n_jumps):
    i_0 = break_indexes[i]
    slice_ = slice(i_0, break_indexes[i+1])
    ax2.plot(x[slice_]-x[i_0]+x[0], errors[slice_]+offset*i, label=dates_test[i_0])
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
ax2.set_xlim(x[0])
ax2.legend()

fig2.tight_layout()
fig2.show()
```

[image: Pieces separated]

Then I thought you could find it useful to use the start of each time block as the ticks, although this can lead to superposition of the labels:

```
# use blocks as ticks:
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots(nrows=3, figsize=(8, 6), sharex = True)
ax3[0].plot(xaxis, errors)
ax3 = ax3[0].twiny()
ax3.plot_date(x, errors, fmt="r-")
ax3.set_xticks(x[break_indexes][:-1])
ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m \n%H:%M'))

fig3.tight_layout()
fig3.show()
```

[image: Useful ticks]

And finally I thought you might want to remove those gaps but keep the tags in the right place:

```
# use blocks as ticks and eliminate the gaps:
# (could have used the inverse of this to create those gaps)
x_without_gaps = x.copy()
delta = x[1] - x[0]
for i in range(1,n_jumps):
    i0 = break_indexes[i]
    i1 = break_indexes[i+1]
    if i1 == -1:
        i1 = None
    x_without_gaps[i0:i1] -= x_without_gaps[i0] - x_without_gaps[i0-1] - delta

#x_without_gaps += x[0]
fig4, ax4 = plt.subplots(nrows=3, figsize=(8, 6), sharex = True)
ax4[0].plot(xaxis, errors)
ax4[0].set_xlim(0,len(errors)-1)
ax5 = ax4[0].twiny()
ax5.plot_date(x_without_gaps, errors, fmt="r-")
ax5.set_xticks(x_without_gaps[break_indexes][:-1])
ax5.set_xticklabels([date.strftime('%d/%m \n%H:%M') for date in 
                 mdates.num2date(x[break_indexes][:-1])])
# the following line would clear the values placed!
#ax5.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m \n%H:%M'))
fig4.tight_layout()
fig4.show()
```

[image]

Old result with wrong tick labels (data is randomised at each run so the labels on the new example are obviously different, but I didn't want to re-upload every image - trust or try for yourself and verify =op ):
[image: Probably what is wanted]
Notice you can not really see the blue line behind the red, so the matching seems to be fine - as long as you set the `xlim` to ensure that.
[image: Detail of previous picture]

Comment: There's an error in the way the tick labels in the final example are placed, will edit as soon as fixed (or if someone want's to, be my guest).

Comment: Thanks for all this. This indeed looks like the right way to do this, if going down the date2num route. However I was just thinking that, due to the gaps, its just easier to treat dates as strings.

Comment: But if you're trying to do any spectral or time dependent analysis you might need to use numbers - it's up to you to use all data in a bunch or each piece individually. And the last example seems to be "a way I can initially set the "dates" xaxis equal to the "index" xaxis, and then change the tick labels to the corresponding dates?", albeit perhaps a bit over complicated.

Answer (score 1):

This is more difficult than initially thought due to the gaps between time stamps. Rather than treating timestamps as floating, using date2num, it might be easier to treat them as str:

dates_test is an array of timestamps in str format.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, figsize=(8, 6), sharex = True)

ax[0].plot(xaxis, errors)
ax4 = ax[0].twiny()
ax4.plot(xaxis, errors, "r-")
ax4.xaxis.set_major_locator(majorLocator)
ax4.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)

majorDates = [dates_test[i] for i in range(0,len(dates_test),250)]
majorDates = [dates_test[0]] + majorDates
ax4.set_xticklabels(majorDates, rotation = 'vertical')
```

[image]